# Why is there so little written on the greatness of the happiness in Heaven?

Tags: heaven, faith

Jonathan Edwards said that terms such as 'ecstacy' and 'joy' were too meager to describe Heaven but were 'low shadows' of the reality.
This (if so) is obviously hugely exciting and, for me, (as a Christian) it is very inspiring. However, one thing puzzles me. If this is the truth (or most likely truth) how come so little is written on the matter? I have done endless research and few other great theologists seem to have hazarded such a guess. Even CS Lewis (my favourite and, indeed, perhaps the most inspirational speaker of recent years to speak on Heaven and joy) never (or, at least, extreemly rarely) seem to venture a guess as to exactly HOW great Heaven's happiness is.
I take it that it is a 'better place'...but does that mean the great happiness of Earth minus the sorrow...or also a greater form of happiness than can be concieved of here?
Seeing God obviously provides a joy as yet unknown and longed for. I assume this joy is above even the greatness of romantic love here? Or is there no higher quantity of happiness than that but, rather, it is unknown because it is qualitively different?

Hope this is clear (and ok). I seem to have a habit of writing the sort of questions this site objects to as I'm not much of a seasoned pro when it comes to scholarship. Maybe I'll get there in the end.

Comment: Your question may be impossible to answer, in that we cannot know if Heavenly Joy and Earthly joy will be the same. For instance we have joy in our children and family here on Earth, but Jesus said that when we get to Heaven we will no longer engage in Marriage since we will be like the Angels. Joy in Heaven may only be in the joy of worshiping God.

Comment: I also think this will be difficult to answer; like you said, the terms "joy" and "ecstasy" describe mere shadows of the actuality of heaven. If our strongest words come nowhere near the reality, what more *can* we say?

Comment: Thanks.But was Edwards right in saying our strongest words come nowhere near the reality? Are there levals to happiness (as, I'm pretty sure, Thomas of Aquinas thought) or is utter bliss available- but short lived and tainted by sin- here? I guess it's the difference between the idea that Heaven is ineffible VS the idea that Heaven is basically Earth without the problems that come with it.

Comment: Is the question as stated or is it busy being made up in the comments?

Comment: As stated. But feel free to answer my comment, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I wish I could help.

Comment: This question is basically just asking us to justify your impression that little is written. It can only be answered with other opinions.

Answer (score 2):

I would think so little is written on the happiness of heaven due to the fact that once you get there you don't come back to explain the 'Happiness". Christ spoke on Heaven, and to be in His presence...going to be awesome!!

If as Christians we are not in a constant state of communication with our Lord, then we will lose our connection to "Joy". We should be striving to be like Christ and in that we should find Happiness. The very fact that we have "hope" in Him is Happiness. Our flesh does not always support this, and as we mature, we should begin to understand that the Spirit of Christ in us is what pushes us forward until we enter heaven either through death or by His return and our exchange of flesh and blood to our new body.

1 Corinthians 15 
50 Now this I say, brethren, that flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God; nor does corruption inherit incorruption. 51 Behold, I tell you a mystery: We shall not all sleep, but we shall all be changed— 52 in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed. 53 For this corruptible must put on incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality. 54 So when this corruptible has put on incorruption, and this mortal has put on immortality, then shall be brought to pass the saying that is written: **“Death is swallowed up in victory.”[g]**

55 “O Death, where is your sting?[h]
O Hades, where is your victory?”[i]
56 The sting of death is sin, and the strength of sin is the law. 57 ***But thanks be to God, who gives us the victory through our Lord Jesus Christ.
58 Therefore, my beloved brethren, be steadfast, immovable, always abounding in the work of the Lord, knowing that your labor is not in vain in the Lord.***

Hope this helped somewhat. (copied from [Biblegateway.com](http://www.biblegateway.com/))

Comment: I voted up your answer because it is nice but it does not answer the question 'why has so little been written'. I just started reading 'Heaven' by Randy Alcorn and there is very little about heaven itself in it.